# async each callback is called before iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

i have the following routing function:

```
router.route('/api/teamUsersWithStat/:team_id')
.get(function (req, res) {
    var user_stat = academy_team_user_stat.build();
    user_stat.usersByTeam(req.params.team_id, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            async.each(result, function () {
                var i = 0;
                user_stat.findModulesTaken(res.user_id, res.team_id, function (modules) {
                    result[i].modules = modules;
                    i++;
                });
            }, res.json(result))

        } else {
            res.status(401).send("Team not found");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        res.send("Team not found");
    });
});
```

as you can see im using the `async.each` method to collect additional data to my existing array.

However the `res.json(result)` is called  without it running the actual loop.

(i can tell this as in my javascript i am debugging the response).

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling your `res.json` method straight away, you're also reinitializing `i` inside the loop so it's always `0`.

Also, `each` requires a callback in order to procede to the next iteration.

The following is how I'd do it:

```
async.each(result, function (r, callback) {
    user_stat.findModulesTaken(res.user_id, res.team_id, function (modules) {
        result[result.indexOf(r)].modules = modules;
        callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
    if(err)
        return res.json(err);
    res.json(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.json(result)` is called as a function, and therefore invoked immediately. To make sure `res.json` is invoked after the `async.each()`, you need to pass a function as callback:

```
async.each(result, function () {
    ...
}, function(err) {
    if(!err) res.json(result);
));
```